# Finder search not working - weird behavior

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight, search

I have the latest version of macOS Sonoma on my MacBook Air.

I have a Word document named `Pabrai Books.doc` in my Documents folder.

I open Finder and start typing the name of the document in the Search field:

`Pabra` => File shows in the results

`Pabrai` => File shows in the results

`Pabrai B` => File shows in the results

`Pabrai Bo` => File shows in the results

`Pabrai Boo` => File shows in the results

`Pabrai Book` => File **does not** show in the results

`Pabrai Books` => File **does not** show in the results

`Pabrai Books.` => File shows in the results

`Pabrai Books.doc` => File shows in the results

I tried rebuilding the index, but nothing changed. I tried to hide the file extension, but nothing changed.

When I use Spotlight search instead of Finder search, all the above queries come up with the file. So, Spotlight search works fine. When I use Finder, if I choose **Name contains:**, all the above queries come up with the file.

What might be the reason that `Pabrai Boo` finds my file, but `Pabrai Books` (which is the actual file name) does not find it?